# add command to the "Buffers" menu

Tags: menu-bar

Is it possible to ADD commands to the "Buffers" menu?  I'd like to add menu entries for:

- Open new window below current buffer
- Split window
- Close current buffer

...and maybe more.  I'd want to add them after the existing:

- Next Buffer
- Previous Buffer
- Select Named Buffer...
- List All Buffers

Is that possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the automatic generation of the buffer menu is a bit complicated the method to add menu items to the buffer menu is quite simple.
Just add them with `easy-menu-add-item` after `menu-mode` is loaded. The general scheme is:

```el
(eval-after-load "menu-bar"
  (lambda ()
    (easy-menu-add-item nil '("Buffers") ITEM)
    ...))
```

where `ITEM` stands for the item you want to add (see the [doc for easy-menu-define](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Easy-Menu.html) for the syntax of `ITEM`).

The interpretation of the menu entries you specified in your question is a bit difficult.
I interpret these entries as follows:

- Open new window below current buffer: Split the selected window, select the lower window of the split, and find a file in that window.
- Split window: This is pretty clear: `split-window`
- Close current buffer: `kill-buffer`

The following lisp code demonstrates adding menu items to the buffer menu according to your specification (as I interpret it).

You can copy-paste the code into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```
(require 'easymenu)

(declare-function find-file-window-below-selected "ext: ")

(eval-after-load "menu-bar"
  (lambda ()
    (easy-menu-add-item nil '("Buffers") ["Find file below selected window" find-file-window-below-selected t])
    (easy-menu-add-item nil '("Buffers") ["Split window" split-window t])
    (easy-menu-add-item nil '("Buffers") ["Kill buffer" kill-buffer t])))

(defun find-file-window-below-selected (filename &optional wildcards)
  "Like `find-file' with args FILENAME and WILDCARDS.
Split window before vertically and display the new file buffer in the
lower window."
  (interactive (find-file-read-args "Find file in new window: "
                    (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
  (select-window (split-window-below))
  (find-file filename wildcards))
```

Last but not least a short motivation why this method works:

The buffer menu commands are listed in the variable `menu-bar-buffers-menu-command-entries`.
That list is populated by the function `menu-bar-update-buffers` if it is not set yet.
Afterwards `menu-bar-buffers-menu-command-entries` is appended to `global-buffers-menu-map` by `menu-bar-update-buffers`.

Thereby `menu-bar-buffers-menu-command-entries` is not copied but just appended.
Therefore items which you define via `easy-menu-add-item` at the end of `global-buffers-menu-map` end up in `menu-bar-buffers-menu-command-entries`.
The value of `menu-bar-buffers-menu-command-entries` is set when `menu-bar-update-buffers` is called at loading `menu-bar.el[c]?`. It is not reset afterwards and always appended to the automatically generated buffer menu.