# How to add a kill-buffer item at the beginning of the Buffers menu-bar menu?

Tags: buffers, menu-bar, menus

When I want to kill a buffer and I have my hands on the keyboard it's simply
`C-x k RET` but if I have already the right hand on the mouse the `k RET` part is a bit out of reach for my left hand…

Fortunately in the toolbar there is a "kill this buffer" button but unfortunately I turned off the toolbar…

<strike>How can I add a "kill this buffer" entry to the `"Buffers"` menu?</strike>

---

Update²

I have implemented [the solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/42062/9672) proposed in [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59152/kill-buffer-in-buffers-menu#comment92487_59152) but now I see two problems

1. `easy-menu-add-item` postpend to the `"Buffer"` menu, it's ergonomically speaking more logical to have `kill-buffer` at the top, but I can change the position only if I know the string that identifies the menu entry where I want to place `kill-buffer` and the buffer menu is inherently dynamic, so that I don't know how to resolve this issue.
2. <strike>`kill-buffer` still needs keyboard interaction, in the form of a confirmation `RET` in the minibuffer.</strike>I remembered that the toolbar "kill buffer" button did not ask for confirmation, so I activated the toolbar, `C-h k click toolbar` and now in my `.emacs` I have `kill-this-buffer`, issue resolved.

New question: how can I fix <strike>those two issues</strike> the position of the new menu entry?

---

Footnote

Researching this topic I've found [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44441/9672) and [this repo](https://github.com/lawlist/buffer-menu) but I'd rather prefer just a few lines in my `~/.emacs` if possible.

Comment: You have in a very detailed answer from @Tobias [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42042/add-command-to-the-buffers-menu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add command to the "Buffers" menu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42042/add-command-to-the-buffers-menu)

Comment: [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42042/add-command-to-the-buffers-menu)  completely addresses my concerns. I'm voting to close my question. Thanks a lot @Muihlinn

Comment: I've changed my mind, see the edit

Comment: @Drew Thank you for the excellent edit